# How can I enable submit form after all jquery functions has been loaded?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, form-submit

I have a MVC project with razor syntax in partial views. Each view has some jquery functions which load some data in forms. Because of asynchronous loading of functions, it may take some seconds to load all functions in the form. If a user click submit button before loading all jquery functions, data lost will occur.

what is the best solution,please?

My view is look like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="save" />
...
<script type="JavaScript/text">
...
$.getJSON(actionUrl1, function (data) {...});
...
$.getJSON(actionUrl2, function (data) {...});
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility that comes to mind is to block the submit button during the execution of the AJAX request and then unblock it in the success handler. You may take a look at the [`jQuery blockUI plugin`](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) as well which you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks Darin, but I have some different partial view with their jquery in my main view; when view is called, these partial view will be called. I want a jquery function which be called in main view, when all jquery functions has been done. can you help me?

Comment: You could subscribe to some of the global ajax event handlers: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/